# Text underline display line above text instead of below

Tags: flutter, underline, text-decorations, flutter2.0, textstyle

[image]As showing the given image After applying underline decoration text style to the text it shows line above text instead of below in flutter 2.2.

```
 TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                getLocalValue(context, txtTermsNConditions),
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12.sp,
                    fontWeight: fwMedium,
                    color: Color(clrPrimary),
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: I tried your code; it is showing as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a problem with fonts I have used, using another font it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a shortcut just use a `Stack` and place both `Text` and a `Divider` Widget in it and gave then position according to your Requirements that's all.

Answer (score 0):

`style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.overline)` will do the trick see [this link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextDecoration/overline-constant.html) for more information.